# How to commit in git many files

Tags: git

I know how to add and commit one file:

`git add [file name]` and `git commit -m`

but what about if I have many file in different dir. how is the right way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list all of these files in `add` or `commit` command. For instance:

`git add [file name] [file name] [file name] ...`

or

`git commit [file name] [file name] [file name] ... -m 'commit message'`

Answer (score 7):

First add all the files to the stage, for example :

```
git add file1 file2 file3 file4
```

Or whole directories :

```
git add directory1/ directory2/
```

When all are staged you can commit them all at once :

```
git commit -m "All at once"
```

Answer (score 2):

Git Bash supports the use of regular expressions in its add and many other commands.  so say for example you wanted to add all the java files in a directory, you could do something like

```
git add /path/to/dir/*.java
```

as always you can run `git add --help` to find out more on the usage and options git offers.

Comment: I don't know if wildcards etc are thanks to git support or are they just a BASH feature.

Answer (score 2):

Adding on top of @Brovoker answer, there are many ways to accomplish this:

A few examples:

`git add .` will stage everything from the current directory **note**: That will not stage files that have been deleted.

`git add -A` will stage everything including removed files.

You can even use wildcards while adding `git add directory/my*`  will add all the files in the directory that start with `my`

For more information you should checkout the `man git-add` and `man git-commit` for more options.